# How to use powertools-lambda-python's decorators together?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, mypy, pyright

How to use powertools-lambda-python's `@tracer.capture_lambda_handler` with `@event_source`? When using these decorators, I get the error below with Pyright in basic mode:

```
Argument of type "(event: SQSEvent, context: Unknown) -> None" cannot be assigned to parameter "lambda_handler" of type "((Dict[Unknown, Unknown], Any) -> Any) | ((Dict[Unknown, Unknown], Any, Dict[Unknown, Unknown] | None) -> Any) | None" in function "capture_lambda_handler"
```

How can I fix the error?

Should I make the handler receive `Any` as argument and then manually cast it to `SQSEvent`? This seems wrong.

Code:

```
@logger.inject_lambda_context
@tracer.capture_lambda_handler
@event_source(data_class=SQSEvent)
def handler(event: SQSEvent, context: LambdaContext):
   pass
```